# What happened with AHAH?

Tags: 6, forms, javascript, ajax

I notice that all my AHAH forms (in the admin) don't work all of a sudden after I updated Drupal and jquery_update. Now that I am working with building a form with the Form API and want to make it dynamic with AHAH through ahah_helper, it hangs itself.

For example, if I type something into a textfield that is supposed to change on blur, the throbber pops up and I can see that the form is trying to POST the change, but then this error comes up:

> uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /\x3e\n\x3c/div\x3e\n\x3c/div\x3e"

and it says it's from the jquery.min.js file. I am using 1.5.

I have heard that this can be because of conflicting files in other modules, and I have tried several different patches for those modules; none of them work.

Does anyone have an insight on this? Or should I use AJAX instead?

Answer (score 2):

Better late than never...

Well the problem is in the Drupal server response, which is not valid json. You need to patch drupal_js function in commons.inc.

```
diff --git a/includes/common.inc b/includes/common.inc
index 80fc911..084b5fc 100644
--- a/includes/common.inc
+++ b/includes/common.inc
@@ -2551,8 +2551,8 @@ function drupal_to_js($var) {
     case 'resource':
     case 'string':
       return '"'. str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "<", ">", "&"),
-                              array('\r', '\n', '\x3c', '\x3e', '\x26'),
-                              addslashes($var)) .'"';
+                              array('\r', '\n', '\u003c', '\u003e', '\u0026'),
+                              str_replace("\'","'", addslashes($var))) .'"';
     case 'array':
       // Arrays in JSON can't be associative. If the array is empty or if it
       // has sequential whole number keys starting with 0, it's not associative
```

Comment: Does this fix break old versions of jQuery (i.e. 1.2 or whichever ships with Drupal 6) ?